# Detect calling multi requests at same time to server

Tags: javascript, http, request

everyone, I have a problem about HTTP requests: I want to detect calling multi requests (to same url) at same time to prevent from calling it.
For example, I have a bug code - a infinite loop (client-side). This code is calling so many requests at same time to server. I want to prevent that or balance it.
I don't know that someone has resolved this problem yet.
Someone can give me some ideas or algorithms for this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's called "rate limiting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling too many times the request from the client side, you can use a lodash.throttle or lodash.debounce.
If you want to protect the server from too many requests you can use a pattern called rate limiting.
However, in this case, you should probably fix the infinite loop instead

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I want to clear your last sentence that: Of course, I should fix the infinite loop code, but I want prevent consequences of that infinite loop code, before I realize that it's an infinite loop code...

Comment: @maitrungdong did my suggestions work for you? if so, could you mark the answer as correct?